# ERROR 1452 (23000)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm getting this error on my script:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`hbm248_BucherFilms1`.`films`, CONSTRAINT
>   `films_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `countries`
>   (`country`))

I want to use INNODB and dont' understand what is causing that error. All my foreign keys line up. What is films_ibfk_1?

Here is the script.

Thanks!

```
-- create the countries table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS countries;

CREATE TABLE countries (
    country varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(country))
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Countries.csv"
    INTO TABLE countries
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;

-- create the film_stock table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS film_stock;

CREATE TABLE film_stock (
    stock varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(stock))
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "FilmStock.csv"
    INTO TABLE film_stock
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;

-- create the film_gauge table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS film_gauge;

CREATE TABLE film_gauge (
    gauge varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(gauge))
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "FilmGauge.csv"
    INTO TABLE film_gauge
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;

-- create the bw_or_color table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bw_or_color;

CREATE TABLE bw_or_color (
    bw_color varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(bw_color))
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "BW_color.csv"
    INTO TABLE bw_or_color
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;

-- create the crew_roles table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS roles;

CREATE TABLE crew_roles (
    roles varchar (15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(roles))
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Roles.csv"
    INTO TABLE crew_roles
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;

-- create the people table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;

CREATE TABLE people (
    full_name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    people_ID varchar (15) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth DATE,
    date_of_death DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(people_ID))
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "People.csv"
    INTO TABLE people
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;    

-- create the cast_members table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cast_members;

CREATE TABLE cast_members (
    cast_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    full_name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    roles varchar (15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(cast_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(title) REFERENCES films (title),
    FOREIGN KEY(full_name) REFERENCES people (full_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(roles) REFERENCES crew_roles (roles))
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "CastMembers.csv"
    INTO TABLE cast_members
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;


-- create the films table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS films;

CREATE TABLE films (
    title varchar (100) NOT NULL,
    alternate_title varchar (50) NULL,
    year_of_release varchar (15) NULL,  
    country varchar (50) NULL,
    running_time_minutes int (10) NULL,
    footage_lenght_feet int (10) NULL,
    stock varchar (10) NULL,
    gauge varchar (10) NULL,
    bw_color varchar (10) NULL,
    notes varchar (255) NULL,
    print_publications varchar (255) NULL,
    existent_print varchar (255) NULL,
    url_1 varchar (100) NULL,
    url_2 varchar (100) NULL,
    url_3 varchar (100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(title),
    FOREIGN KEY(country) REFERENCES countries (country),
    FOREIGN KEY(stock) REFERENCES film_stock (stock),
    FOREIGN KEY(bw_color) REFERENCES bw_or_color (bw_color),
    FOREIGN KEY(gauge) REFERENCES film_gauge (gauge))
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Films.csv"
    INTO TABLE films
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It could be this line: FOREIGN KEY(film_gauge) REFERENCES film_gauge (film_gauge));  <-- the semicolon is ending the statement

Comment: I tried that and got: ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hbm248_BucherFilms1`.`films`, CONSTRAINT `films_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `countries` (`country`))

Comment: The type of the foreign key must match.  It is varchar(50) in one and varchar(20) in the other.

Comment: I fixed that but it didn't fix the problem. same error still.

Comment: It seems to me to be a very bad idea to have a `film_gauge` column in a `film_gauge` table, and then have a foreign key named `film_gauge` that references `film_gauge(film_gauge)`, but maybe that's just me. It seems a little like George Foreman naming all of his male children *George*; it's probably a little confusing when you're wanting to know which one is being referred to when you read *George was a bad boy today*.

Comment: Ha, yea, but it is just a CV table and only has two possible records. But, I like the boxing simile. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  LOAD the tables in the right order. (Load `Countries` before any table needing `country`.  Etc.)

Plan B:  DISABLE KEYS ... do the LOADs ...ENABLE KEYS

Comment: So, first you loaded `countries`?  Then, you loaded `films`, but it got an error?  What `country` was some film trying to reference?  Is that `country` in `countries`?

Answer (score 0):

"ENGINE = INNODB" is not part of a the create table statement. Remove the first semi-colon for those two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE cast_members (
cast_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar (50) NOT NULL,
full_name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
roles varchar (15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(cast_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(title) REFERENCES films (title),
FOREIGN KEY(full_name) REFERENCES people (full_name),
FOREIGN KEY(roles) REFERENCES roles (roles)); <-- this one
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: I tried that and got: ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'hbm248_BucherFilms1.cast_members' (errno: 150)

Comment: Ken White is correct. Read top reason here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-error-codes.html

Comment: I fixed that but still have : ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hbm248_BucherFilms1`.`films`, CONSTRAINT `films_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `countries` (`country`))

Comment: A value for `country` in films.csv may not exist in table countries.

Comment: that is not the case, other than a blank cell. But i set countries in the film table to be NULL so I figured that would not be a problem.